# How do I fork and patch transient node modules with NPM?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I use browserify and would like to make a change to their `browser-pack` dependency where they   use UMD. I created a fork and would like to use this forked `browser-pack` in my project.

I know how I can point a dependency to a github URL but how do I change the transitive dependency of `browserify` to make use of my forked `browser-pack`?

Of course only a solution that works across the team (without having everyone to set it up) is a good solution for me. Given the case that my `package.json` looks like the following.

```
{
    "name": "X",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "browserify": "^4.2.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using npm-shrinkwrap, or are you checking node_modules directly into git? If you're not doing either of those, I think you're in for some pain. Otherwise, you should just be able to swap out that dependency by hand and your version control will keep it locked.

Comment: I have to admit I'm doing neither shrink-wrap nor checking in node_modules. What technique would you recommend me? Using npm-shrinkwrap and then modify the precise dependency?

Comment: You either need to shrinkwrap and change the dep manually or also fork browserify and change it's package.json to use your new fork of browser-pack

Comment: @codevour you definitely should be using either shrinkwrap or putting node_modules in git. If you do that, this problem effectively goes away because the entire dependency tree gets snapshotted and frozen. That's why you should be doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a solutions seems to be like @d11wtq pointed it out, to use `npm shrinkwrap` unfortunately we have to redo the changes everytime we add a new dependency to `npm`. Thanks anyway to everyone contributing to this questions.